# Can only push notification once on Xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-notifications

I am making a reminder app with Xamarin. I am trying to send notifications, however every time I run the app I can only push one notification no matter how many reminders the user creates.

Here is my notification code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using ReminderApp.Models;
using ReminderApp.HelperRepository;
using Android.OS;
using System;
using static Android.Media.Audiofx.BassBoost;
using Android.Media;

namespace ReminderApp.Notifications
{
    [Activity(Label = "ReminderApp")]
    public class ReminderNotifications : Activity
    {
        Reminder reminder;
        public ReminderNotifications()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            string CHANNEL_ID = "dan1414";
            int NOTIFY_ID = 0 + new Random().Next(1, 30);

            var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.Default)
            {
                Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel"
            };

            string date = Intent.GetStringExtra("date");
            string time = Intent.GetStringExtra("time");
   

            reminder = ReminderHelper.SelectReminderByDateAndTime(this, date, time);
            if (reminder != null)
            {
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(ReminderContent));
                newIntent.PutExtra("reminder", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reminder));

                Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
                stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(ReminderContent)));
                stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(newIntent);

                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

                Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .SetContentTitle("Reminder!!")
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Screenshot_2020_11_11_at_4_57_02_PM)
                .SetContentText("Click for details..");
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
                notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
                notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFY_ID, builder.Build());
            }
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.NotificationAlert);
        }
    }
}
```

I see nothing wrong with my code and I have tried many different things, but nothing works.

here is my full code, in case it helps: https://github.com/CrazyDanyal1414/ReminderApp

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `ScheduleReminder` method, please modify the PendingIntent second parameter like this:

```
   PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, new Random().Next(), myIntent, 0);
```

making sure the unique value for PendingIntent second parameter, otherwise the new alarm  will be overwrittethe old alarm.

```
public void ScheduleReminder(Reminder reminder)
    {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(AlarmService);
        Intent myIntent;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(ReminderNotifications));
        myIntent.PutExtra("date", reminder.Date);
        myIntent.PutExtra("time", reminder.Time);

        var t = reminder.Time.Split(':');
        var ampm = t[1].Split(' ')[1];
        var hrr = Convert.ToDouble(t[0]);
        var min = Convert.ToDouble(t[1].Split(' ')[0]);

        string dateString = Convert.ToString(reminder.Date + " " + hrr + ":" + min + ":00 " + ampm);

        DateTimeOffset dateOffsetValue = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateString);
        var millisec = dateOffsetValue.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

        PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, new Random().Next(), myIntent, 0);
        manager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, millisec, pendingIntent);
    }
```